# Second line in ggplot is not showing correct linetype and also not in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently had some code that produced exactly the `ggplot` in R that I was looking for. After updating my `ggplot` package recently, that code no longer works as I wanted. The new plot no longer shows the correct linetype for my horizontal line. Nor does the line show up in the legend. As I said, it used to work perfectly.

Here is a quick, reproducible example using the `mtcars` dataset (my real data cannot be shared):

```
    model <- lm(mtcars$wt ~ mtcars$hp)
    mtcars$pred <- predict(model, mtcars, level = 0)

    theme<-theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold"),
         axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, face="bold", colour="black"),
         axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12),
         axis.text.y = element_text(angle=90, face="bold", colour="black"),
         plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"),
         panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'black'),
         panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = NA),
         panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
         strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'))

    plot<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = pred)) +
      geom_point(aes(x=hp, y=wt, color = as.factor(am)), position=position_jitter(width=0.5,height=0.5), alpha = 0.5) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 4.5, size = 1, aes(linetype = "y = 4.5")) +
      geom_line(aes(linetype= "Best fit"), size = 1) +
      scale_y_continuous(name= "Weight") +
      scale_color_manual('AM', values = c('orange', 'purple')) +
      scale_linetype_manual('Lines', values = c("Best fit" = 1, "y = 4.5" = 2)) +
      xlab("Hewlett Packard") +
      guides(linetype = guide_legend(keywidth = 2, keyheight = 1)) +
      theme

    plot
```

Here is the plot:
[image]

The `y=4.5` line should be dashed, but as you can see it is still solid. Furthermore, it is not showing in the legend. Another thing I noticed is that the legend titles formatting have changed. They used to be bold but are not anymore.

Can anyone help me to fix my code? Also can anyone explain why this changed?

Comment: There was a breaking change in the ggplot package version 2, take a look at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md to see what was affected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `yintercept = 4.5` inside the `aes()` of `geom_hline()` and then legend and corect linetype will be used.

```
  +geom_hline( size = 1, aes(yintercept = 4.5,linetype = "y = 4.5"))
```

Comment: That works well. Now let's take `geom_abline` and do the same thing: `+geom_abline(size = 1, aes(intercept =3, slope = 0.01, linetype = "y = 4.5")`. When you do this, it prints the dashed line and everything shows in legend, but now you get this weird diagonal line through the legend markers.

Comment: Actually I just resolved it on my own, although i'm not exactly sure why this works: `+geom_abline(size = 1, aes(intercept =3, slope = 0.01, linetype = "y = 4.5"), show.legend = FALSE)`.